# C# merge 2 datatables based on columns content

Tags: c#, sql-server, merge

I hope you can give me a hand, I have two Excel tables imported into a SQL Server database now I need to create a new table by merging the two tables I have.

The problem is that they have not a common key value to create a relation. I want to create a third table to get a bill number from the table1 and assigned to the table2 based on the date, hence the only common field would be the date.

I guess I can use 2 datatables and this would do the job by merging them, however I'm not sure how to merge datatables based on the date column to assign the bill number, I'll need to create a loop to review the dates values and assigned the bill number accordingly. But not sure how to do it.

Please give me a hand.

Table 1

```
Customer | Bill Number | Date  | Original | Currency| 
---------+-------------+-------+----------+---------+
16FR951  | 489641      | 1-May | 598898   | CRC     |
```

Table 2

```
Customer ID | Date  | Currency | Transfer ID | Total | 
------------+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
RJ028       | May-2 | BRZ      | 15587878    | 50000 | 
FR016       | May-1 | CRC      | 18989899    | 89898 |
```

Expected table should have the bill based on the date like this:

```
Customer | Bill Number| Date  | Transfer ID | Currency| 
---------+------------+-------+-------------+---------+
16FR951  | 489641     | 1-May | 18989899    | CRC     |
```

Comment: 1) back up your tables firstly in case things go wrong. 2) create a temp table and do an `insert into temp table select from first join 2nd on date 3)see if temp table has what you want 5) if yes, delete the data from original table and insert into original table (this will be the merge stuff). if no, drop the temp table and change your query until you have desired result

Comment: Table 1
Customer | Bill Number| Date   | Original | Currency|
16FR951  |489641       | 1-May | 598898 | CRC       |

Table 2
Customer ID | Date     | Currency  | Transfer ID | Total     |
RJ028           | May-2  | BRZ          | 15587878   |  50000  |
FR016           | May-1  |CRC          | 18989899   | 89898  |
Expected Table Should have the Bill based on the date like
Expected Table
Customer | Bill Number| Date   |  Transfer ID| Currency|
16FR951  |489641       | 1-May | 18989899   | CRC       |

Comment: But I'm not sure how to assign the bill number based on the date.

Comment: Vertical Partitioning would work but I have no primary key that is being shared between tables, I want to add the bill number in this new third table to set is as primary key, I mostly need the Bill number for the transact ID number then I'll be capable to know which transaction ID belongs to a specific bill

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [Table 1] AS a INNER JOIN [Table 2] AS b ON a.Date = b.Date`. Maybe I don't understand your question.